# Как пишется

Tags: правописание

ни к чему

Answer (score 1):

ПОЧЕМУ ПРЕДЛОГ РАЗБИВАЕТ МЕСТОИМЕНИЕ НА ДВА СЛОВА

Мне показалось интересным замечание Инны по поводу приставки НИ, которая умеет превращаться в частицу НИ, и хотелось бы предложить чисто авторскую версию, объясняющую это явление.

В словарях для слова НИЧТО приводятся примеры, которые можно свести к двум основным вариантам: а)пустое место/множество в утвердительных предложениях; б) местоименное существительное в отрицательных предложениях. Например: (1) Для системы отдельный человек – это ничто, он нужен чтобы функционировала система. (2) Ничто не имело своего действия.

Посмотрим, как строятся отрицательные предложения. Например: (3) Ему хотя бы один предмет интересен?. - (4)Ни один предмет ему не интересен. (5) Ему хотя бы что-то интересно? - (6)Ему ничего не интересно. - (7) У него нет интереса ни к чему.

Частица НИ в приведенных примерах является формально-усилительной, она обеспечивает переход от утвердительного предложения к отрицательному. Такое впечатление, что предложение (6) можно записать в виде (8)"Ему ни чего не интересно", и такая раздельная запись частицы НИ похожа на ее запись в предложении (7) с предлогом.

ВЫВОД: изначально существуют два варианта: "ничто" (утв. предл.) и "ни что , ни чему, ни чем, ни к чему, ни за что" (отриц. предл.), однако отрицательный вариант при отсутствии предлога (ничто, ничем и др.) имеет слитное написание по аналогии с утвердительным вариантом, чтобы не осложнять орфографию. Но при наличии предлога используется раздельное написание частицы НИ.

Comment: > Но при наличии предлога используется раздельное написание частицы НИ.

Но ведь частица никогда не пишется слитно. 
Я тоже обратила внимание на комментарий Инны. В школе нам говорили, что НИ остается приставкой. Мы даже выделяли её как приставку. Так это , оказывается, частица при раздельном написании слова?

Comment: Среди частиц выделяется группа словообразующих  и формообразующих частиц. Словообразующие частицы (не, ни, то, либо, кое, нибудь) выступают в качестве приставок и суффиксов. При слитном написании НИ - это приставка. При раздельном написании НИ может быть одиночной частицей в отрицательных предложениях (ни один не пришел), а также входить в состав союза НИ...НИ. Таким образом, частица НИ выполняет различные грамматические функции. По поводу школьного разбора не могу сказать определенно, но считать, что приставка пишется раздельно - это как-то странно.

Answer (score 0):

так и пишется. ни к чему

Answer (score 0):

В местоимениях частица НИ пишется в безударном положении (под ударением - НЕ), а раздельное написание связано с тем, что между частицей НИ и местоимением ЧЕМУ находится предлог К. Если Вас устраивает ответ, кликните "принять ответ"

Comment: Было "ничто"(где НИ - приставка).стало "ни к чему". Приставка превратилась в частицу? Или что произошло?